# Resetting STDOUT and STDERR with /dev/tty

Tags: stdout, stderr, tty

I am trying to redirect stdout and stderr to a file, and then restore them back to their original settings. I have successfully redirected the output to a file, but I can't seem to restore them from the tty. This is the code that I have:

```
            fid = open("/dev/tty", O_WRONLY);
            if (fid < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Opening TTY failed.");
                exit(1);
            } else {
                close(1);
                dup(fid);

                close(fid);
            }
```

the open call on tty always fails. (returns -1). Is there something fundementally wrong that I'm trying to do?

I also though that maybe it might be a permissions issue, so I checked them:

crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    2,   0 Oct 21 10:46 /dev/tty

I am developing on Snow Leopard for what its worth,

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just an additional note: I printed out the error using perror. It says that 'Device not configured'.

Answer (score 0):

I would just save the previous settings away with a `dup` call, then use `dup2` when you want to restore them. This is *especially* true since the "original settings" you wish to set them back to may not be the terminal device at all (that's an unwise assumption on your part) - the user may have already used redirection outside of your sphere of influence.

That way you don't have to worry about re-opening them at all, including the possibility that you may get the arguments wrong or have to do any special setup (such as with `ioctl`).

Something along the lines of:

```
int saveFd = dup (1);        // check for errors.

blahBlahBlah();              // close file desc 1, reopen,
                             //   and weave your magic.

int rc = dup2 (1, saveFd);   // check for errors.
```